# Determine (with justification) whether the series converges or diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine (with justification) whether the series:

k=1 to ∞ ∑  (π/2)^k

converges or diverges, if it converges, find its exact sum.

This is what I came up with:

We note this is a geometric series with r = π/2 and a = π/2. Since the absolute value of r >= 1, the geometric series is divergent.

Does that sound right?

Comment: Righty. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

We note this is a geometric series with r = π/2 and a = π/2. Since the absolute value of r >= 1, the geometric series is divergent.